MKMapView not retaining state?
I have an extremely simple set up in which a MapKit resides within another view. I want the map to be able to be expanded into a fullScreenCover. The map properly shows up in ProfilePageView on initial load, and properly shows up in the fullScreenCover when expanded. However, when the fullScreenCover is exited the map is effectively totally gone (see image below). Clicking on the rectangle again properly sends it back to the fullScreenCover where it is displaying correctly.

I can force it to rerender by using a UUID key, but this seems like a hack and I don't understand why it is necessary.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct ProfilePageView: View {

    @State private var isMapExpanded: Bool = false

    @State private var mapView: MKMapView
    @State private var mapViewKey: UUID = UUID()

    init(countryNames: [String]) {

        // Initialize MKMapView with configuration
        let initialMapView = MKMapView()
        let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.9391, longitude: 67.7100)
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 6000000
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: initialLocation, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
        initialMapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
        _mapView = State(initialValue: initialMapView)
        print("MKMapView initialized in init")
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                Divider()

                Button(action: {
                    isMapExpanded = true
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        MapUserView(isMapLoading: .constant(false), mapView: mapView)
                            .id(mapViewKey)  // Use the key to force recreation
                            .frame(height: 425)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                            )
                            .allowsHitTesting(false)

                        Rectangle()//
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                            .frame(height: 425)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isMapExpanded, onDismiss: {
                    print("FullScreenCover dismissed")
                    mapViewKey = UUID()  // *If this is commented it we get the above described image*
                }) {
                    MapUserFullScreenView(isPresented: $isMapExpanded, mapView: mapView)
                }

            Text("Here we are")

                
            }

        }
    }




struct MapUserFullScreenView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var mapView: MKMapView
   

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            MapUserView(isMapLoading: .constant(false), mapView: mapView)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button(action: {
                isPresented = false
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ProfilePageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let randomCountries = ["Brazil", "Colombia"]
      
        
        return ProfilePageView(countryNames: randomCountries)
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct MapUserView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isMapLoading: Bool
    
    var mapView: MKMapView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        print("UI has been made")
        // Ensure the map view is only configured once
        if mapView.delegate == nil {
            mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        }
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView called")
        // Ensure the map view is not reset or cleared unintentionally
        if mapView.delegate == nil {
            mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapUserCoordinator {
        MapUserCoordinator(self)
    }

    class MapUserCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapUserView
        
        private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        var dimmingView: UIView?

        init(_ parent: MapUserView) {
            self.parent = parent
            
            super.init()
        }

        func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            parent.isMapLoading = false
        }
        
    }
}


struct MapUserView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        return MapUserView(isMapLoading: .constant(false), mapView: MKMapView())
    }
}

Why is this UUID key necessary? Why isn't @State properly ensuring the state of the mapview remains shared within the ProfilePageView and that of the value displayed in the fullScreenCover?
Note that I am passing mapView to MapUserView to enable the fullscreencover to display without requiring a full reload of the map information (I have stripped out a lot of the complex methodologies here to focus on the specific problem). Prior to passing this mapView, the button would cause the map to entirely reload before displaying and this would cause significant lag.

MKMapView is an UIKit class. @State is for value types. And the class should not be retained in a SwiftUI view anyway. Nevertheless use native Map in SwiftUI

While I have stripped this out, I am using MKMapView because I need to render polygon overlays. My understanding it that Map cannot do this. Hence using the former. Assuming this is a correct rationale, how can I ensure that the MKMapView renders once when the ProfilePageView loads, and can be re-rendered when the user interacts with it through the fullScreenCover, but the simple act of expanding and closing the fullScreenCover causes no reloads?

makeUIView needs to init the MKMapView
SwiftUI View structs shouldn't have a custom init because you will slow its diffing down.
You asked how to write code to init a map, like this:
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
     let map = MKMapView()


Can you elaborate a bit? How would this be done in the code? Also 1. I am not sure who “diffing” means and 2. So nothing can be init’d in a swiftUI view?

Ok I added the code to show how to write a make func. 1 - diffing is how SwiftUI works, it diffs the View structs comparing old vs new and uses that diff to create and update UI objects, depending on the platform. 2. Yes.

I appreciate the update. My question wrt to the init is specifically to ensure that this approach enables the following capability:  map is loaded upon opening of profilepage. Toggling between the map in the fullscreencover and in the profilepage should maintain the same state. Ie no reloads. I’ve stripped out some of the more complex methods, but the user should be able to modify the state of the map in the expanded view. This should propagate to the map in the profile view as well. But simple expanded to not expanded toggling shouldn’t reload anything.
